# program to install firefox exetension in windows?

Tags: installation, firefox-addon, command, executable

Is it possible to build a installer(or program) in windows 7, that can install extension to firefox (if the browser installed on the machine).

or atleast help me by providing command to install firefox extension through command line in windows7.

("firefox addon.xpi" command is available in linux)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Installation of extension in Firefox is very simple.

You need to launch Firefox.exe with your .xpi file as parameter

The official documentation says you should use **-install-global-extension** switch (not sure why, it should worked also without it, at least in older versions it did).

```
firefox.exe -install-global-extension "<path>\extension-file.xpi"
```

Details here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

If you want to create whole installer with this feature, let's say in NSIS:

```
Function InstallFirefoxExt
  InitPluginsDir
  SetOutpath "$PLUGINSDIR\" 
  File "extension-file.xpi" # Extract file to temporary directory
  Exec '"<path>\firefox.exe" -install-global-extension "$PLUGINSDIR\\extension-file.xpi"'   
FunctionEnd
```

If you use other installation system it is very similar.

Comment: Thanks. The above command giving the error "firefox.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". if i replace firefox.exe with the full path, it is working fine. so i need a command to get the path of installed firefox/ running firefox path.

Comment: Yes, you need to get full path fo firefox - e.g. from Registry.

Comment: how can I instal the extension without opening a new firefox window?

Comment: That is probably blocked so the user is always informed what is happening. Probably because of installing some suspisious extensions.

Answer (score 1):

To install a Firefox extension on Windows you should simply [add a value to the Windows registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry). This can be done by opening a `.reg` file or running `reg.exe` with the right parameters, a custom Windows application to add it would also be trivial. Adding to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` can be done without advanced privileges (no UAC prompt), adding to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (for all users) requires administrator privileges.

I would advise against using `-install-global-extension` since that adds the extension to the Firefox application directory - you have to know where Firefox is installed, administrator privileges are always required and updating/uninstalling the extension is non-trivial. Also, `firefox addon.xpi` will install into the default user profile - in addition to the disadvantages of `-install-global-extension` this doesn't consider the fact that more user profiles could exist on the computer (or be created in future).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox path can be detected by reading this registry key:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\20.0.1 (en-US)\Main" "PathToExe"
```

On my PC this PathToExe looks like "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" so this is exactly the value you need.

However this is a little tricky because the key contains Firefox version 20.0.1 (en-US)
To get this version at first read this key:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox" "CurrentVersion"
```

which will return **20.0.1 (en-US)**

Simply join all parts together:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\" + <CurrentVersion> + "\Main"
```

to get whole key.